does nodejs's eval() would change the behavior of var keyword?
all these code snippets run in nodejs.
below are demo1.js, ps: run these code in nodejs rather than browser js engine
// demo1.js

var1 = 'var1';  // in nodejs or Chrome-V8 js engine, this line would create a property named var1 into globalThis/this/window obj
console.log("[globalThis.var1]:", globalThis.var1);  // var1

globalThis.var2 = 'var2';
console.log('[var2]:', var2);  // var2

var var3 = 'var3';  // in nodejs, this line would not create a property named var3 into globalThis
console.log("[globalThis.var3]:", globalThis.var3);  // undefined

function baz() {
  var var4 = 'var4';  // in nodejs, this line would not create a property named var4 into globalThis
  console.log('[globalThis.var4]:', globalThis.var4);
}
baz();  // undefined

(function () {
  var var5 = 'var5';  // in nodejs, this line would not create a property named var5 into globalThis
  console.log('[globalThis.var5]:', globalThis.var5);
})();  // undefined

I can understand every thing in demo1.js.
below are demo2.js, ps: run these code in nodejs rather than browser js engine
// demo2.js

(function() {
  (0, eval)("var foo = 123;");  (0, eval)("var foo = 123;");  // indirect call eval，create a property named foo into globalThis, which means create a global scope variable foo.
  (0, function() { console.log('[globalThis.foo]:', globalThis.foo); })();
})();
console.log('[globalThis.foo]:', globalThis.foo);  // 123
console.log('[foo]:', foo);  // 123

In demo2.js, I do konw the comma operator would change the eval execution scope to global scope, and also according to Direct and indirect eval - MDN page:
screenshot from MDN eval
My question is:
demo1.js the function baz code block var var4 = 'var4' or the IIFE code block var var5 = 'var5', in nodejs these two line would NOT create a property into globalThis.
But demo2.js the IIFE code block, var foo = 123, in nodejs this line create a property into globalThis.
In both demo1.js and demo2.js, since variables are declared using the var keyword(like var var4 and var var5 in demo1.js, var foo in demo2.js), why is only the var declaration in demo2.js create a property into globalThis?

You said "I can understand every thing in demo1.js.", what's your reasoning as to why var var3 = 'var3'; didn't create a property on globalThis, do you understand why it behaves like that?

@NickParsons yes, I understand why var var3 = 'var3' didn't create a property on globalThis, cause it declare a module scope variable which not in global scope, and @EfeKarakaya told me that browser treat each module top-level's var declaration as global scope, and thats why in browser var var3 = 'var3' would add a property named var3  to globalThis.

NodeJS will automatically wrap your file's code in a function if you're using CommonJS (by default, if your package.json lacks a type, it'll be treated a commonjs by default):

Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a
function wrapper that looks like the following:
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // Module code actually lives in here 
});


So, to explain why demo1 works the way it does:

Any variables assigned without var such as var1 are automatically made global and become properties of the global object, hence why you can see it on globalThis.

top-level var declared variables such as var3 would normally also appear on the global object, but since node wraps your code in a function shown above, the var is now function-scoped. Any var declared inside a function belongs to that function's scope; it is not global.  Hence, why var3 doesn't actually get added to globalThis (but does in your browser console)

var4 and var5 are both declared as var inside of functions, so these variables are function-scoped and not global, and so don't get added to globalThis.


The important part is the second dot-point, as var3 doesn't actually sit in the top-level global scope, it's not added to the global object. Now in demo2.js, as you're using indirect eval the below line of code
var foo = 123;

is able to escape the wrapper function Node normally adds, and is now ran in the global scope. As var declared variables in the global scope become properties of the global object, you're able to see it when logging globalThis.

"Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a function wrapper that looks like the following:". I didnt know that at all, thanks for pointing it out, and could you put a nodejs docs link about it?

@Lucas No worries, the link is right there already (on "automatically wrap")

oh I saw it, my bad bro.

Variable Declarations with var:
When you define a variable with var in a normal function or block, this variable becomes comprehensive in that function or block. That is, it does not appear in the global scope or in globalThis.
Direct and Indirect eval:
demo2.in the js file, the line (0, eval)("var foo = 123;") uses an indirect call of the eval function. In JavaScript, when the eval function is called indirectly, it executes its code in a global scope.
In particular, the indirect eval call causes the foon to be added to globalThis.
Function Scope demo1.For js:
demo1.in the js file, both the base() function and IIFE do not use the eval or comma operator directly. Therefore, the variables defined by var (var4 and var5) remain specific to those functions and are not added to globalThis.
Summary of Differences
demo1.For js:
var4 and var5 remain local and are not added to globalThis because they are defined in function scopes (either in a named function or in IIFE).
demo2.For js:
since the eval function is called indirectly by (0, eval)("var foo = 123;"), foo defined in the global scope. This is a unique behavior of indirect eval.
So, the crux of your question is about the difference in execution context due to how eval is invoked. The use of the comma operator and indirect eval causes foo to be created in the global scope, while the direct variable declarations in demo1.js remain scoped to their respective functions.

in demo1.js not only var4 and var5 remain local and are not added to globalThis, but also var3 is not added as a property to globalThis either(yea, even if var3 is not defined in function scopes), I do konw if demo1.js run in Chrome-V8, that condition var var3 = 'var3' will be added as a property to globalThis/this/window. but in nodejs, var3 just not, you can try it.

The key difference is that in demo2.js, the variable foo is explicitly assigned to globalThis, whereas in demo1.js, the variables var4 and var5 are not. This explicit assignment is what makes foo a property of the global object in Node.js.

I mean demo1.js var var3 = 'var3' and demo2.js var foo = 123, they are all executed in global scope with nodejs js engine, why only demo2.js var foo = 123 be added to globalThis?

and also, for example, execute this line in module top-level scope - var myVar = 'demo', it seems like there's a difference between nodejs and Chrome-V8, Chrome-V8 will add myVar to globalThis, but nodejs will NOT add myVar to globalThis.

This difference arises because Node.js uses the CommonJS module system, where each file is treated as a separate module with its own scope. In contrast, browsers treat the top-level scope as the global scope, making var declarations global. If you want to add a variable to the global scope in Node.js, you can explicitly assign it to globalThis:
globalThis.myVar = 'data';
console.log(globalThis.myVar);

do you mean nodejs treat each module(js file)'s top-level var declaration as the module level scope(not the global scope), but browser(esm module) treat each module(js file)'s top-level var declaration as the global scope? Can I understand it in this way?

Yes, your thought is correct.

pretty thanks the clarification about the difference between nodejs and browser how to treat the module top-level var declaration, which is save my day. I think my problem been solved due to this point.
